# Hashset vs Array, is further optimization possible?

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a code that works like the following all throughout my program. One example would be pathfinding, where I create snapshots of a dynamic environment and use the created map as basis for the aStar-algorithm.

As the execution time of the code impacts the maximum amount of units I can have utilizing the pathfinding, I'd like to optimize here as much as possible.

The (I believe) performance optimal solution would be this:

```
  static int runtest(bool[,] coll, int size, int globalSize)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int x = -size; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -size; y < size; y++)
            {
                if (coll[x+ globalSize, y+ globalSize])
                {
                    counter++;

                    int tx = x;
                    int ty = y;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

However I'm not happy with the amount of wasted memory when using arrays, so I am currently using this solution:

```
static int runtest(HashSet<int> coll, int size)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int x = -size; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -size; y < size; y++)
            {
                if (coll.Contains(calculateHash(x, y)))
                {
                    counter++;

                    int tx = x;
                    int ty = y;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

 public static int calculateHash(float x1, float y1)
        {
            int x = (int)Math.Floor(x1);
            int y = (int)Math.Floor(y1);

            return calculateHash(x, y);
        }

      //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static int calculateHash(int x, int y) {
            return x + (y << 16);
        }
    }
```

The Array implementation is about 5 times faster, is this something I have to live with or can I somehow optimize the hash-version further?

Full Test Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 240;
            HashSet<Vector2> VecHash = new HashSet<Vector2>();
            HashSet<int> intHash = new HashSet<int>();
            bool[,] boolArr = new bool[size * 2, size * 2];


        for (int x = -size; x < size; x++) {
            for (int y = -size; y < size; y++) {
                VecHash.Add(new Vector2(x, y));
                intHash.Add(calculateHash(x,y));
                boolArr[x+size, y + size] = true;
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start");
        Console.ReadLine();

        int reps = 1000;
        int testSize = 180;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        while (true) {
            long counter = 0;
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                counter += runtest(VecHash, testSize);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks + "\tVecHash items: \t" + counter);
            counter = 0;
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                counter += runtest(intHash, testSize);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks + "\tIntHash items: \t" + counter);
            counter = 0;
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                counter += runtest(boolArr, testSize, size);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks + "\tboolArr items: \t" + counter);
            sw.Reset();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


    static int runtest(HashSet<Vector2> coll, int size)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        var allrelevant = coll.Where(a => a.x >= -size && a.x < size && a.y >= -size && a.y < size);
        foreach (var item in allrelevant) {
            counter++;

            float tx = item.x;
            float ty = item.y;
        }

        return counter;
    }
    static int runtest(HashSet<int> coll, int size)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int x = -size; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -size; y < size; y++)
            {
                if (coll.Contains(calculateHash(x, y)))
                {
                    counter++;

                    int tx = x;
                    int ty = y;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
    static int runtest(bool[,] coll, int size, int globalSize)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int x = -size; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -size; y < size; y++)
            {
                if (coll[x+ globalSize, y+ globalSize])
                {
                    counter++;

                    int tx = x;
                    int ty = y;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static int calculateHash(float x1, float y1)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(x1);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(y1);

        return calculateHash(x, y);
    }

  //[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static int calculateHash(int x, int y) {
        return x + (y << 16);
    }
}

public struct Vector2
{
    public readonly float x;
    public readonly float y;

    public Vector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what the memory goes `wasted when using arrays`?

Comment: @Maarten I am using the array as a 2d map. Some fields have objects in them, and thus are set to true, otherwise they are set to false. In the method above I do something if there is something in that location of the map. All the fields that are set to false are wasted space. A hashset avoids this, as it only stores values that are actually there.

Comment: How big are the arrays? Is there an actual memory problem?

Comment: @Maarten depends on the start and target-position of the pathfinding. So the arrays can be 10*10 to 25000*25000

Comment: Using a jagged array instead of a multi-dimensional array is an easy win.  Cuts out a bunch of index out-of-range checks.  Using *unsafe* code will be faster yet.

Comment: @hans-passant if I use a jagged array the index can't be used as a coordinate on a map anymore

Comment: If the 2-d array is booleans and you are worried about space -- I can only assume that you have millions or billions of booleans in this array if you are worried about it; memory is cheap -- then you can use bit arrays to cut down memory usage by a factor of 8; you pay for that in decreased speed. Or, if there is a lot of redundancy, you can use memoized quadtrees to cut down the memory burden to a tiny fraction; you can represent quadrillions of booleans easily with a memoized quadtree.

Comment: But in general, unless you have data structures that are a significant fraction of a billion bytes, don't worry about it. Memory is extremely cheap. Every process gets two billion bytes of address space even on 32 bit architecture.

Comment: @eric-lippert the boolean is just here as a placeholder, in the real environment it's an array of an interface, and memory becomes an issue fast if you have hundreds/thousands of concurrent pathfinding instances going on

Comment: Was thinking on this problem again and I was going to suggest the bit arrays bit that Eric did, but I was blown away by the Quadtree idea.  It's a pretty good one - I've never applied them except in the context of Image compression, so it didn't come to mind.  It handles extreme sparsity very well, and still does pretty good on speed.

Answer (score 1):

Classic space/size tradeoff.  HashSets, and other hash-style data structures, must use a hashing algorithm to provide the O(1) speed we use them for.  In .NET this is done through the .GetHashCode() method that is part of every object.

That is where part of the slowdown comes from - you are executing a hash function, along with a number of other functions with the Contains and what it calls, including InternalGetHashCode and many others.  So you throw a number of extra things on the stack, and their state, etc.

Thus, you're really not going to get much faster than this giant 2D array.

Comment: I am aware that the array version I posted is probably the optimal one. What I'm asking for is possible small optimizations for the hashset version

Comment: There aren't really any big ones to be made from what I'm seeing on your code. The implementations are identical, modulo the overhead of the HashSet implementation.  You might be able to eke some speed out of it with a custom ValueType that contains your X,Y and a custom hash function.  Might also try getting rid of the Floor calls, casting to an Int does that all by itself.

Comment: casting to an int truncates the value, which is the same as floor for positives, but a ceil for negatives, I need the same behavior for both positive and negative numbers

Comment: Maybe a hybrid approach is appropriate: default to arrays and if the size of your array is greater than some threshold, fall over to hashsets.